# What's an efficient way to filter this array?

Tags: ember.js

My data structure is

```
companies = [
  {name: 'A', ramps: [1, 2]},
  {name: 'B', ramps: [3, 4, 5]}
  ...
]

ramps = [
  {id: 1, division: 'accounting', amount: 500},
  {id: 2, division: 'sale', amount: 200},
  ...
]
```

My goal is to end up with the following data:

```
groupedByDivision = [
  {division: accounting, total: 12000},
  {division: sales, total: 6500},
  ..
]
```

My first brute-force approach is something like this (note: I've extended Ember.Array with this [flatten](https://gist.github.com/mehulkar/3232255) method:

```
var ramps = this.get('controller.companies') // this is the array of companies
  .get('model')
  .mapProperty('ramps')
  .flatten();

var temp = {}, data = [];
$.each(ramps, function(index, ramp) {
  if ( !(ramp.billingDiv in tempCompanies) ) {
    temp[ramp.billingDiv] = ramp.feeChange;
  } else {
    temp[ramp.billingDiv] += ramp.feeChange;
  }
});

$.each(temp, function(division, amount) {
  data.push({
    'category': division,
    'count': amount
  });
});

return data;
```

Any other suggestions? I'm not too familiar with the [Ember.Array](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html) methods yet, so I'm not aware of all their use cases.

Comment: it might be easier as an intermediate step to create `groupedByDivision = { accounting: 12000, sales: 6500 .. }`

Comment: also could you explain in more detail how `companies` affects the end result?

Comment: re: your first comment, that's basically what I'm doing. temp has each division as a key, and just adds to it the amount of each ramp in that category. Then I change the structure into an array. Re: your second comment, it doesn't. It's just that my data is coming in as an array of companies, which is why I have to first flatten it.